# Calculating credit payments in Python

Tags: python

Beginner in Python. I have to write a program that produces a table displaying a "credit card" type of balance over however many months it takes to pay off the balance with the minimum payment. I think I've figured out most of it, but I'm running into a problem.

The problem is how to end the loop once the balance is paid off while also making the final payment equal to balance. Since the minimum payment is greater than the balance of the last payment, I end up with a negative number as my end balance. I've tried to fix this by adding an if-then statement to my loop, but I end up with a payment of .04, and the example output I'm provided with zeros-out at $3.80.

The code I have so far:

```
listedPrice = 200

print("%10s%20s%20s%20s%10s%20s" % \
     ("Month", "Starting Balance", "Interest to Pay", "Principal to Pay", "Payment", "Ending Balance"))

downPayment = listedPrice / 10
balance = listedPrice - downPayment
interestRate = .12
interest = (balance * interestRate) / 12 
payment = (5 * balance) / 100
principal = payment - interest
numPayments = 24

for month in range(1, numPayments +1):
    balance = balance
    interest = balance / 100
    principal = payment - interest
    endBalance = balance - payment + interest
    print("%10s%20.2f%20.2f%20.2f%10.2f%20.2f" % \
        (month, balance, interest, principal, payment, endBalance))
    if endBalance < payment:
        payment = endBalance
    balance = endBalance
```

Alternatively, I’ve tried the following with a while loop:

```
month = 1

while balance > 0.0:
    balance = balance
    interest = balance / 100
    principal = payment - interest
    endBalance = balance - payment + interest
    print("%10s%15.2f%15.2f%15.2f%15.2f%15.2f" % \
        (month, balance, interest, principal, payment, endBalance))
    if endBalance < payment:
        payment = endBalance
        balance=endBalance
        month+=1
        break
    balance = endBalance
    month +=1
```

The problem is that the final row of the table stops with a payment of $9 and ending balance of $3.80. It should have one more row with a payment of 3.80 and ending balance of 0.

Thanks to Zach Mohammed for the idea of the break command!

Comment: Did you try changing this to `while balance >= 0.0:`. Check for greater than or equal to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also a novice at Python, but I love solving these problems. It helps me understand the language better and improve my problem solving skills with each one of these I resolve.

Even though I am aware this is not the 'cleanest' or 'most efficient' code, I can still explain what is wrong and what I did to fix it, and I am sure you can go from there and figure out other solutions.

This is how I solved your two questions:

```
listedPrice = 200

print("%10s%20s%20s%20s%10s%20s" % \
     ("Month", "Starting Balance", "Interest to Pay", "Principal to Pay", "Payment", "Ending Balance"))

downPayment = listedPrice / 10
balance = listedPrice - downPayment
interestRate = .12
interest = (balance * interestRate) / 12 
payment = (5 * balance) / 100
originalPayment = (5 * balance) / 100
principal = payment - interest
numPayments = 24

for month in range(1, numPayments +1):
    balance = balance
    interest = balance / 100
    principal = payment - interest
    endBalance = balance - payment + interest
    if payment == 9:
        print("%10s%20.2f%20.2f%20.2f%10.2f%20.2f" % \
            (month, balance, interest, principal, payment, endBalance))
        if endBalance < payment:
            payment = endBalance
        balance = endBalance
    elif payment <= originalPayment and balance != 0:
        payment = balance + interest
        principal = balance
        endBalance = 0
        print("%10s%20.2f%20.2f%20.2f%10.2f%20.2f" % \
            (month, balance, interest, principal, payment, endBalance))
        balance = endBalance
        print("\n It took",month,"months to pay off your credit card.")
```

This goes from month 1 through 23; since month 24 will be 0 dollars and should not be displayed. It then lets you know how many months it took.

Your problem was you were not breaking out of the loop on the last line and changing the print statement; along with the calculation that needs to occur to give you the final minimum payment line, finish the loop, and then tell you how many months it took.

**Note:** I added the .04 interest for the last payment so it is 3.84 payment, if for whatever reason the last payment is not suppose to have interest included, you can simply take it out of the last *'elif statement'*. I do notice you say you do not want it though in your original question.

But since it is a credit card, I think the last payment should technically have interest, even if it is four cents. But, if your instructions are to have no interest on that last payment, just remove it from the last loop in the *'for statement'*.

You should be good to go, then!

Comment: This is really clever, thanks! I was able to use the gist of your idea in my while loop. with the final code being: month = 1

while balance > 0:
    balance = balance
    interest = balance / 100
    principal = payment - interest
    endBalance = balance - payment + interest
    balance = endBalance
    if endBalance <= payment and balance !=0:
        payment = endBalance
        balance = endBalance
        month+=1
        balance=0
    month +=1
    print("%10s%15.2f%15.2f%15.2f%15.2f%15.2f" % \
        (month, balance, interest, principal, payment, endBalance))

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy to help firstly I've not been able to replicate the issue that you got yourself with $3.80 being displayed incorrectly but you were nearly there I've added a break after the if statement which will break out of the loop:

```py
if endBalance < payment:
        payment = endBalance
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with the break command. I didn’t state my problem clearly. The example output that I’m given ends with a balance of 3.80 and a payment of 3.80, not $9. Also, the number of months variable that I added was just to help me work on one part of the problem. My final code shouldn’t specify the number of months (I think?). So I originally tried a loop with “while balance >0” but that didn’t work.